# Evolution - Not all replies added in e-mail thread

Tags: email, evolution

I am using Evolution (version 3.10.4) on Ubuntu (version 14.04.2 LTS trusty).

Occasionally, when I receive a reply to an original e-mail that I send OR I receive a reply to an earlier e-mail that I received in my Inbox, the reply I receive is not added into the e-mail thread AND/OR an e-mail thread is not created.  Thus, the e-mail is alone and/or separate from other e-mail(s) directly related to it.

**Why are not all the replies I receive added to my e-mail thread and/or create an e-mail thread?**

**How do I make all replies I receive add to or create an e-mail thread?**

I assume this is something that can/must be fixed on my end.  **Correct?**

I assume it is unlikely that the person replying can determine how my e-mail client (Evolution) interprets their e-mail.  **Correct?**

Usually, when I receive a reply (or someone replies to an original e-mail I received earlier) an e-mail thread is created (i.e., the reply received is grouped with any other e-mails linked to the original e-mail that was sent, and it is indented in a chronological format).  However, there are a couple e-mail addresses from which I receive a reply that tend to not create an e-mail thread and/or be added to the thread.